# Group IEnumerable into a string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco

I wonder if someone could spare me a few minutes to give me some advice please?

I've created an `IEnumerable` list:

```
public class EmailBlock
{
    public int alertCategory { get; set; }
    public string alertName { get; set; }
    public string alertURL { get; set; }
    public string alertSnippet { get; set; } //Need to work out the snippet
}

List<EmailBlock> myEmailData = new List<EmailBlock>();
```

Which I then loop through some data (Umbraco content - not that that's really relevant!) and add items to the list.

```
 myEmailData.Add(new EmailBlock { alertCategory = category.Id, alertName = alert.GetPropertyValue("pageTitle"), alertURL = alert.NiceUrl });
```

What ultimately I'd like to do is group the list by the `alertCategory` and then load each 'group' (another loop occurs later to check what members have subscribed to what alert category) into a variable which I can then use as an email's content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq has a nice group by statement:

```
var emailGroup = emailList.GroupBy(e => e.alertCategory);
```

Then you can loop through each grouping and do whatever you want:

```
foreach(var grouping in emailGroup)
{
  //do whatever you want here. 
  //note grouping will access the list of grouped items, grouping.Key will show the grouped by field
}
```

Edit:

To retrieve a group after you have grouped them, just use `Where` for more than one or `First` for just one:

```
var group = emailGroup.First(g => g.Key == "name you are looking for");
```

or

```
var groups = emailGroup.Where(g => listOfWantedKeys.Contains(g.Key));
```

this is a lot more efficient than looping through every time you need to find something.

Comment: #oliver #pquest Cheers folks, so that groups everything together (Thanks for that). Is then possible to load the each group in a string (or series of strings) that I can get hold of later?

Comment: @SxChoc you mean just load the keys into a list of strings?

Comment: I'm probably not explaining this very well! What I'll end up with is half a dozen grouped 'things' I'd then like to load each group into a unique variable so that later in code I can check a series of users to check what alertCategory they're signed up for and inject the relevant string/s into an email and then send it.

Comment: @SxChoc so if say the alertCaregory was foo, you would want `var foo = emailGroup.First(g=> g.Key == "foo")`?

Comment: That's sorta what I'm after but the alertCategory isn't a fixed number of categories so I'd need something dynamic (apologies if I'm being stupid here...I've been awake for too long!)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just look through the emailGroup object keys each time?

Comment: Hi pquest (sorry it's taken a while to respond), I could loop through the emailGroup and bring the string that way. I'm just concerned that if I've got say 500 people signed up for emails then I'd need to loop through each one and then loop through the emailGroup per person. Just thinking that it might be really intensive

Comment: @SxChoc I edited my post with details about how to efficiently get to the groups.

Comment: Mate your an international superstar!

Answer (score 4):

You could use Linq's [`GroupBy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534304(v=vs.100).aspx) to do this:

```
using System.Linq
...

//Create a type to hold your grouped emails
public class GroupedEmail
{
    public int AlertCategory { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<EmailBlock> EmailsInGroup {get; set; }
}

var grouped = myEmailData
    .GroupBy(e => e.alertCategory)
    .Select(g => new GroupedEmail
    {
        AlertCategory = g.Key,
        EmailsInGroup = g
    });
```

You can select to an anonymous type if required and project your sequence into whatever structure you require.